# Explain the code below dealing with regular expressions in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Explain the below code:

```
$x = '12aba34ba5';

@num = split /(a|b)+/, $x;   
gives   # @num = ('12','a','34','a','5')

@num = split /(?:a|b)+/, $x;
gives # @num = ('12','34','5')
```

Comment: [Regular expressions in Perl](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

Comment: First you should read some basic tutorials about `Perl regular expressions` and then if you didn't understand something ask here.

Comment: @serenesat i did but still have a doubt ,that's why i ask here

Comment: You should right that doubt in your question.

Comment: Anyway some people have already explained. So if you understand then you can accept any answer and close this as solved and do the same for previous questions you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are capturing `(a|b)` so `a` gets captured.`(a|b)+` will match `aba` but only `a` will be stored as regex remembers only the last one when continuous groups are there.So split is at groups of `ab` in any order .In the second case you dont capture `(a|b)` .So you get the correct split result.

Answer (score 0):

The string `12aba34ba5` is being split on occurrences of multiple `a` or `b` characters, giving the result `12`, `34`, `5`

However, you also have a *capture* in the split regex, which inserts the captured string into the `split` list

If you write `'aba' =~ /(a|b)+/` then there are three occurrences of the pattern `(a|b)`, but only the *last* one can be saved in `$1`, and this is the value that `split` inserts

So you are picking up the last value of `aba` (`a`) and the last value of `ba` (another `a`) and inserting them into the list, giving `12`, `a`, `34`, `a`, `5`

If you wanted the letters separated from the numbers, you could write

```
@num = split /((?:a|b)+)/, $x;
```

or, equivalently and more neatly

```
@num = split /([ab]+)/, $x;
```

giving `12`, `aba`, `34`, `ba`, `5`